# How to get Windows 10 to understand Scheduled Tasks?

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

I've got a short vbs script that I need to run daily.

Here is the vbs script:

```
Dim URL 
URL = "C:\Users\jp2code\Coding\DailyEmail.html"

Dim objShell 
set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "chrome.exe", URL, "", "", 1
```

I can double-click the file in Windows Explorer, and the HTML file will open up in Chrome. Just like I want.

I have it specified to run as a daily task in Task Scheduler, but every day Windows 10 barfs and can't figure out what to do with the vbs file:

[image: screenshot]

It would be faster, at this point, to just have a Message Box pop up, but I would like to get it fixed.

Has anyone found a way to tell Windows 10 how to handle things like this?

It is almost like this whole OS was designed to be run on a tablet {cough!}.

Comment: for the record, you can right-click scheduled tasks and run them on-demand instead of waiting for the interval to pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To launch a VBS script from the Task Scheduler, you need to specify which [scripting host engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678441/difference-between-wscript-and-cscript) to run it with.

Using `cscript` ("Console Script") is probably most appropriate for tasks.

So set the "Start a program" under "Actions" to `cscript` and set the "Add arguments" to your script path/name (e.g.: `c:\pathTo\yourScript.vbs`).

Comment: Windows 10 cannot seem to find either `cscript` or `wscript` (from your link). Is that something additional that needs to be installed?

Comment: @jp2code It should be `C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe`

Comment: an exemple using .py script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44873579/1486850